# Issue converting list to NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list that consits of 2000 rows and 88200 columns:

```
testlist = list(split_audio_to_parts(audio, self.sample_rate, self.audio_index))
```

debugging output of `testlist` gives

```
[array([-0.00683594, -0.00689697, -0.00708008, ...,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ]), array([-0.01287842, -0.01269531, -0.01257324, ...,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ]), array([0.02288818, 0.01940918, 0.01409912, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.00772095, 0.00671387, 0.00695801, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]),
```

and so on.
`split_audio_to_parts` is a function:

```
def split_audio_to_parts(x, sample_rate, audio_index):
for i, row in audio_index.iterrows():
    x_part = x[int(row['start_samples']):int(row['end_samples'])]
    yield x_part
```

When I try to convert it to numpy array using `samples = np.array(testlist)` or `samples = np.asarray(testlist)`, it gives me array of shape (2000,), although debugging shows that `testlist` consits of 2000 entries with 88200 positions. Why so? I'm using 64bit numpy and 64bit Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Are you sure `testlist` is a list of lists? Could your print the first entry or to and post them for example?

Comment: Please do not post stuff like that in the comments, or in an image. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50068431/edit) button to improve your question, and post the example in a code block.

Comment: Good edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `testlist` is a list of different size arrays. For example checkout this code:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>import random 
>>>random.seed(3240324324)
>>> y=[np.array(list(range(random.randint(1,3)))) for _ in range(3)]
>>> y
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0])]
>>> np.array(y)
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0])], dtype=object)
>>> np.array(y).shape
(3,)
```

and the array would be of `object` type instead of float. the only way for this to work is having same sized arrays.

If you really need to stuff these rows somehow into an array you can pad with zeros, for example:

```
>>> size = y[max(enumerate(y),key=lambda k:k[1].shape)[0]].shape[0]
>>> z=[np.append(x,np.zeros(size-x.shape[0])) for x in y]
>>> z
[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 0])]
>>>np.array(z).shape
(3, 3)
```

but you would have to decide how you do this padding.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of arrays. If each array in your list does not have the same length, your conversion will not be successful.

Here is a minimal example.

```
A = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]

A_2 = np.array(A)
# array([array([1, 2]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)

A_2.shape
# (2,)
```

If the lengths of your arrays are aligned, you will find no problem:

```
B = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]

B_2 = np.array(B)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])

B_2.shape
# (2, 3)
```

---

To check the sizes of your arrays, you can use `set`:

```
array_sizes = set(map(len, A))
```